# How can I config google pubsub to use queue mechanism?

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using Google pub-sub (java) as a pub and as a sub.

I couldn't find a way to enable queues mechanism.

Meaning if publisher sends messages before the subscriber is up,

then messages are not lost and wait for the subscriber to fetch.

Maybe when i create the channel?

```
public void init(final String projectId, final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    this.projectId = projectId;
    if (inputStream != null) {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
                FixedCredentialsProvider
                        .create(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(inputStream));

        channelProvider = TopicAdminSettings.defaultChannelProviderBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
    } else {
        channelProvider = TopicAdminSettings.defaultChannelProviderBuilder()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud Pub/Sub, the subscription must have been created before the message was published in order for a subscriber on that subscription to receive the message. After the subscription is created, any messages published will be delivered to a subscriber that comes up for that subscription. individual messages are retained for attempted delivery for up to seven days. Typically, one would create the subscription via the [Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub).

Comment: There is no way to configure a queuing mechanism? in case the subscribers were down? I don't want to lose messages

Comment: If the subscribers go down after the subscription was created, the messages will still be retained and delivered when the subscribers come back. The distinction between subscriptions and subscribers is important here. The subscription is all that has to be created before the messages are published. There is no way to create a new subscription and receive messages published prior to its creation. Subscribers can go up and down and messages are retained and delivered when the subscribers come back (for up to 7 days).